# R CMD CHECK Note: information on .o files is not available

Tags: r

In RStudio, using devtools and Hadley Wickham's R Packages book procedures on a macbook, I do the Shift-CMD-E to do the equivalent of a R CMD CHECK and I have 0 errors, 0 warnings and 1 note that is persisting :

```
  Note: information on .o files is not available
```

This note also would persist with Travis CI on my github repo.

I have compiled code: in my /src directory are .c, .f, .fsrc, .h, .o, and .so files as well as a Makefile.

I've googled and there doesn't seem to be any definitive answers out there [[1]](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Note-information-on-o-files-is-not-available-td4691767.html).  I'd like to eliminate the note to smooth the way for CRAN submission, although the google search also revealed a few packages on CRAN that have this note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At bare minimum:

1. Try removing the Makefile from /src and build again.

Which may be all that is needed.  When I was resurrecting some old packages that had a Makefile in the /src and tried to do R CMD Check with RStudio removing the Makefile removed the note (the note was also removed from the Travis CI build on the github repo of the aforementioned package).  The Makefile looked like this:

```
LIBNAME=rmutil

OBJS=   cutil.o dist.o gettvc.o romberg.o toms614.o

$(LIBNAME)$(SHLIB_EXT): $(OBJS)
    $(SHLIB_LD) $(SHLIB_LDFLAGS) -o $@ $(OBJS) $(FLIBS)

clean:
    @rm -f *.o *.$(SHLIB_EXT)

realclean: clean
```

In addition,

2. Add the .fsrc, .o, and .so files to the .Rbuildignore file, with

   \.fsrc$
   \.o$
   \.so$

Comment: I'm having the issue describen in the question. I don't have any Makefileand I added those files to the .Rbuildingnore and still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the .o files and rebuild/recheck the package?

Comment: Yes, I tried to upload it to CRAN and seems to pass the pretest. Maybe a path issue...

Answer (score 1):

To understand this message we can go to the R source which is producing this (I searched my local copy with `grep -Fr "information on .o" . --include=*.{c,R}` to find this); it's in the `tools` package's file `sotools.R`:

https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/82cbdc1c0bffe062a0b1e269daf00008c46b044f/src/library/tools/R/sotools.R#L719-L726

```
        objects_symbol_tables_file <- if(nzchar(r_arch))
            file.path(dir, "libs", r_arch, "symbols.rds")
        else file.path(dir, "libs", "symbols.rds")
        if(file_test("-f", objects_symbol_tables_file)) {
            tables <- readRDS(objects_symbol_tables_file)
            bad <- Filter(length, lapply(bad, compare))
        } else if(useST)
            cat("Note: information on .o files is not available\n")
```

`file_test` is `tools:::file_test`, the `-f` is checking that the files listed in `objects_symbol_tables_file` (1) exist and (2) are not directories.

`r_arch` is `.Platform$r_arch` (`''` on my personal x86 Ubuntu);

`useST` is the truth value of the environment variable `_R_SHLIB_BUILD_OBJECTS_SYMBOL_TABLES_` (more details on this in the [R Internals manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html));

IINM `dir` is the package directory.

This isn't a full answer for why this warning is showing up & how to fix it, but it should be a lot of ammo for debugging further.